# Responsabilidade de registro de dependências (IoC, DI, arquitetura n-layer)

Tags: c#, .net, injeção-de-dependência

Estou iniciando um projeto em WPF (.NET/C#) utilizando uma arquitetura n-layer (Domain Driven Design), e para implementar a Inversão de Controle e Injeção de Dependências (IoC/DI), estou tentando utilizar o Unity Framework da Microsoft.

A dúvida que tenho é com relação a responsabilidade de registro das dependências, seria correto deixar que a camada de apresentação crie o container e realize o registro das dependências necessárias?

Ou TODAS estas dependências devem ser registradas na camada de Infraestrutura?

Ou ainda, as duas coisas? Por exemplo: a camada de apresentação registra coisas como Views e a camada de Infraestrutura realiza o registro das dependências que são comuns a todas as camadas?

Comment: Marcos sua dúvida foi sanada? Pergunto pois sua pergunta ainda está em aberta.

Answer (score 3):

> ...seria correto deixar que a camada de apresentação crie o container e realize o registro das dependências necessárias?

**Não.**

A Camada de Apresentação é responsável pela exibição de informações do sistema ao usuário.

A Camada de Infra-estrutura  é responsável por fornecer recursos técnicos que darão suporte às camadas superiores. Ou seja, essa última sim deve ter esse tipo de preocupação.

**Alguns problemas que você pode ter ao registrar o container e suas dependências na camada de apresentação:**

Como você está utilizando uma arquitetura seguindo *Domain Driven Design* (DDD), você provavelmente terá uma Camada de Negócios, onde "serviços" irão depender de consultas a repositórios.

Nesse cenário, dependendo de sua implementação, seu projeto de negócio (chamado Domínio no DDD) dependeria diretamente do seu projeto da Camada de Apresentação, o que é incoerente a abordagem DDD.

Outro cenário que você pode ter problema: Se a Camada de Apresentação do seu projeto mudar no futuro para Asp.Net MVC, Web Form, etc.. você terá que ficar alterando/movendo esse código que resolve/registra as dependências, ou seja, você terá maior manutenção e mexendo nesse código de novo :-(.

**Registre as dependências na Camada de Infraestrura.**

> ...Ou TODAS estas dependências devem ser registradas na camada de Infraestrutura?

Sim, no que diz respeito a dependências comuns aos projetos/camadas, principalmente Repositórios e Serviços.

> ...Ou ainda, as duas coisas? Por exemplo: a camada de apresentação registra coisas como Views e a camada de Infraestrutura realiza o registro das dependências que são comuns a todas as camadas?

Como registrar/resolver dependências não é responsabilidade da Camada de Apresentação, te aconselho a fazer o registro das dependências na Camada de Infraestrutura, assim você tem um ponto único e não precisa ficar dando manutenção em dois lugares.

Comment: Renan, me expressei mal quando disse "coisas como Views", eu quis dizer registar ViewModels. Posso por exemplo ter uma interface chamada IServerViewModel que irá ser implmentada posteriormente para controlar o comportamento da UI (XAML), neste caso, o registro das dependências deve ser feito na camada de apresentação, correto?

Comment: Eu não registraria na camada de apresentação. Se você precisa consumir isso "entre as camadas da sua aplicação", com o objetivo de manter um baixo acoplamento entre as camadas/módulos, então recomendo que você registre a dependência na camada de Infraestrutura.

Comment: Mesmo se a aplicação possuir mais de um tipo de camada de apresentação? Por exemplo WPF e WEB (ASP.NET MVC)

Comment: Sim, imagine salvar um Cliente no sistema por exemplo, quando o usuário clicar em Salvar, seja via WPF ou Asp.net MVC, a regra de negócio é a mesma, "as dependências de repositórios e serviços que o sistema irá resolver também são as mesmas".

Comment: Quanto as regras de negócio: sim, elas devem ser registradas na camada de infra, mas uma interface que será utilizada apenas para controlar algo relacionado apenas à tela, deve mesmo ser registrada na infraestrutura? Se eu tiver 3 ou mais tipos de apresentações (WEB, Mobile, Desktop, etc) registrar isso tudo em um único lugar, me parece um pouco estranho.

Comment: Estranho é você registrar uma dependência na camada de Apresentação. A camada de Apresentação é responsável pela exibição de informações do sistema ao usuário. Já a camada de Infra-estrutura fornece recursos técnicos que darão suporte às camadas superiores.
Ou seja, essa última sim deve ter esse tipo de preocupação.